# Google Script getActiveRange

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet with two sheets inside named "Sheet1" and "Sheet2". I have a script, running on click the menu item:

```
function foo(){

var oSheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"),
oSheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
Logger.log(oSheet1.getActiveRange().getValues());
Logger.log(oSheet2.getActiveRange().getValues());

} // foo
```

I select in browser in Sheet1 the first range, and then click on Sheet2, and select the second range, different on the first. I click the menu item, start foo(). Logger view same result for oSheet1 and oSheet2. Why? And how I can to get selected range on unactive sheets?

Here is the table with full access https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lfQl9H1PW2lKL-4YJir7uxl-ZMnDR6Zn1_FndG07WGY/edit#gid=1264703349

Comment: The First Range Image — https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBdtF.png The Second Range Image — https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qcivq.png

Comment: It works if you put a ';' semicolon after line 1 and a var at the start of line 2.  Of course, you'll have to view logs and you'll be looking at a couple of two dimensional arrays.  So it won't look exactly like your spreadsheet.  But you should get use to moving your data around this way because it's at least an order of magnitude faster that messing with cells.

Comment: Cooper, you mean
function foo(){
    
var oSheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var oSheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
Logger.log(oSheet1.getActiveRange().getValues());
Logger.log(oSheet2.getActiveRange().getValues());
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(oSheet1.getActiveRange().getValues());
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(oSheet2.getActiveRange().getValues());

} // foo — I would be surprised if a semicolon saved the situation. And this case log show two same results with different sheet's selections.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I was wrong.  It looked like it was working but it was taking the active range in whatever sheet was sitting on top when the function runs. I tried it by avoiding to use active range like below and it does work. I put the Sheet1 and Sheet2 in there with all the asterisks so I could see the beginning of each data set to insure that they were the correct data. But even though there are selected ranges in each of the sheets the function repeats the selected data on the upper sheet (whichever one is active) and it doesn't report any errors.

```
function foo(){

var oSheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getDataRange();
var oSheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2").getDataRange();
Logger.log('**************************Sheet1**********************' + oSheet1.getValues());
Logger.log('********************Sheet2**************************' + oSheet2.getValues());

} // foo
```

Comment: If you wanted to do something like this you could do it in a multistep operation.  First select range on first page and store that information in  PropertiesService.DocumentProperties then get the second range and store it and then collect the data utilizing those stored ranges.